# IIS 7 ASP.NET 4.0 Ignoring Default Document

Tags: asp.net, iis-7

We have a ASP.NET 4.0 web application upgraded from 3.5. Unfortunately when the user tries to access the URL via http://xxx.abc.com/, the user gets /login.aspx?ReturnUrl=%2f.

I understand that this seems to be a behaviour on .NET 4.0 and IIS7. This is causing an issue with load balancer as it returns **302 status** code. Some reason the 
load balancer has been configured to look for http **200 status** code.

Is there any way we can fix the ASP.NET 4.0 behaviour so that when user clicks on http://xxx.abc.com/, show the login.aspx without redirection?

I tried this below but did not work:

```
<system.webServer>
    <defaultDocument>
      <files>
        <add value="Login.aspx" />
      </files>
    </defaultDocument>
</system.webServer>
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not a behavior of .NET 4 / IIS 7, it's a behavior of forms authentication.  It seems that the Authentication module gets run first, and triggers the redirect before the Default Document module gets its chance.  Here's what I would suggest as a workaround:

- set `<allow users="?" />` on the root of your website by using the `location` tag.
- if the above is not possible or practical, use the [URL Rewrite module](http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) instead of relying on Default Document.

I used this rewrite rule to get `login.aspx` returned from the root URL with a 200 status code :

```
<rewrite>
  <rules>
    <rule name="RewriteURL1" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{REQUEST_FILENAME}" matchType="IsFile" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Rewrite" url="login.aspx" />
    </rule>
  </rules>
</rewrite>
```

Comment: Use <match url="^$" /> to match empty URL (e.g. domain only URL)